# Creating rules having complex conditions using multiple data objects

Tags: drools, rule-engine

Assume that I have two data objects `Person` and `Address`. Person object has the fields `name` and `gender` and Address object has the fields `city` and `state`. Now I want to take some action based on this condition :

```
when
    (person.name == 'jayram' && address.city == 'barhiya') || 
    (person.gender == 'M' && address.state == 'bihar')
then
    do something
```

How to accomplish this in drools rule file?

Comment: Have you read the section on DRL (Drools Rule Language) in the Drools manual?

Comment: @laune No, what does it say?

Comment: It contains things you need to know.

Comment: @laune I went through the manual, but I couldn't find anything related to my scenario.

Comment: You didn't even get the syntax right, so I'm not sure what your "scenario" is. You need to *understand* what DRL constructs mean: then you won't have any problems implementing a presumably simple scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this should be the solution:

```
package com.sample

dialect "mvel"

import com.sample.Person;
import com.sample.Address;

rule "Hello World"
    when
        person : Person( status == Message.HELLO)
        Address((person.name == 'jayram' && city == 'barhiya') ||
 (person.gender == 'M' && state == 'bihar'))
    then
        // Do something
end
```